# How install electrum for other users on Windows?

Tags: electrum, windows

I installes electrum on admin usage.

For security reasons I do not want to use admin account to use the wallet (the computer has no other use). I want to use normal account.

So I created another account.

It turns out that electrum not available on other accounts.

So I reinstall electrum on that other account.

I still don't see electrum shortcut anywhere. Not in desktop not in start up menu. Nowhere.

That strategy works with Exodus but not electrum.

So I can't use electrum on the non admin account and I have no idea why. Installing it will delete existing electrum on previous accounts and reinstall it again, but do not put any shortcut.

It's simply not installed.

My guess is electrum actually installed on all devices and I need to do is to create that default shortcut. However, there is no easy way to do so.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Electrum's github, this issue appears to be Windows-specific and is caused by `pyinstaller` (an upstream dependency) running under the admin context. This means that the installer will only create icons and shortcuts for the admin account, even when run from a user account.

Take a look at https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/issues/3219 and https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/issues/2558 for more information. This seems fixable, either from modifying how electrum uses `pyinstaller` or by submitting a fix to `pyinstaller` directly.

Comment: Or temporarily turn the non admin account into admin account

Answer (score 0):

It looks like electrum is not designed to be installed on non admin account.

So I changed the account into admin. I install electrum and I got things working

Comment: For more context, this issue is Windows-specific and appears to be an upstream issue with pyinstaller. Take a look at https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/issues/3219 for more information.